# Strange error of undefined reference while compiling on Linux

Tags: c++, g++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

I got the following error while compiling in g++ 4.5.5 on Linux while allegedly my code works fine on Windows.

```
A.o: In function `A::NewObj(int)':
A.cpp:(.text+0x39): undefined reference to `List<A>::Add(A*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [program] Error 1
```

I have no idea what is wrong with my code. I'm not sure if I declared object list_A correctly.

The files:

#### A.h

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

class A
{
public:
    int key;
    A() { key=0; }
    A(int i) { key = i; }
    void NewObj(int i);
};

#endif
```

#### A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
#include "List.h"

static    List<A> *list_A = new List<A>();

void A::NewObj(int i)
{
    A *nobject = new A(i);
    list_A->Add( nobject );

}
```

#### List.h

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

template<typename Objct>
class Node
{
public:
    Objct* datapiece;
    Node *next, *previous;

    Node() { next = previous = 0; }
    Node ( Objct *object, Node *n = 0, Node *p = 0)
    {
        datapiece = object;
        next = n; previous = p;
    }
};

template<typename Objct>
class List
{
public:
    List() { head = tail = 0; }
    void Add( Objct* );
protected:
    Node<Objct> *head, *tail;
};

#endif
```

#### List.cpp

```
#include "List.h"
#include <iostream>

template<typename Objct>
void List<Objct>::Add( Objct *o )
{
    int i =5;
    Node<Objct> *nnode = new Node<Objct>(o);
    if ( o->key < i )
    std::cout << "Ok" << std::endl;
}
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "A.h"
#include "List.h"

int main()
{
    A *magazyn = new A();
    magazyn->NewObj(6);
}
```

#### makefile

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -pedantic

program: List.o A.o main.o
    $(CC) List.o A.o main.o -o program
A.o: A.cpp List.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) A.cpp
List.o: List.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) List.cpp
main.o: main.cpp A.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.cpp
```

Comment: The problem is that you [have to implement templates in the header file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the fact that your template class `List` needs to have its methods defined in every compilation unit that uses it.  Templates usually don't follow the one header, one implementation file rule.  See this related question for more information:  [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: Thank you very much! This was precisely the case. I wouldn't get it on my own.

Comment: However I fixed my issue through explicit instantiations, the solution using the `#include` directive didn't work for me. Putting all in one file either. Why?